# Redirect to my fb.admin site while requesting to create an app-id for my website

Tags: facebook, app-id

First:I have a facebook account for a website, not for my person.

The problem: All times I'm trying to create an app-id for my website, I get redirected to my facebook account - whether I'm logged in or not.

There are at least 4 kinds of request that I've checked out:
- directly from my fb.admin site
- http://developers.facebook.com/apps
- http://developers.facebook.com/tools/

Why I don't can call any fb:developer page? Knows anyone what's wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating and managing a Facebook app from a Business Account](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10805745/creating-and-managing-a-facebook-app-from-a-business-account)

Answer (score 0):

You have to be logged in as a person(!) and must be registerd as developer. Then you can reach all developer sites including 'create an application'. Otherwise you will be redirected to your fb.admin page.